# Is there a Unitary matrix such that determinant is $z$ where $|z|=1$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S^1$ be a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|=1$.

Let $M$ be the set of $n\times n$ Unitary matrices. (n>1)

Then, is $\det:M\rightarrow S^1$ surjective?

Comment: No, think of $n=1$ case.

Comment: @OfirSchnabel What if $n>1$?

Comment: Still no, determinant always real since eigenvalues are reals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You changed to unitary so now the answer is yes.
Just take diagonal matrix 
$$diag(1,z).$$

Comment: no problem, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

For hermitian, since all eigenvalues are real the determinant is also real. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant "Unitary matrix"..